# Libgdx Shader plus Filter

Tags: image, libgdx, shader

I need to paint my character, and to do so im using a Shader. Its pretty ok so far. 
The character contains black, and 4 scales of a color.
Now i'm facing a problem that i cant find a reasonable solution.

My shader uses scales of a color to decide where to paint. I works perfectly with 32x48 images. But, to make a more detailed image, i'm trying to use 64x96 
(due to creative limitations). To make that kind of image, i try two things:

First - Create the image in ilustrator, which leads to one problem: Ilustrator exports image with some kind of linear filter (similiar to what Linear filter does in Libgdx).  When i use this image, the border pixels get mixed with the black lines, making it out of the coloring range i made. In result, the shaders paints the wrong pixels.

Two - Create the image pixel by pixel (in 64x96) in any editor. This works ok, but leads to two problems. First problem is that the screen isn't big enough for the image, so it uses the Libgdx filters to fix the display. If i use Linear, i get the same scenario that i get in Ilustrator, where it paints the wrong pixels. If i use Nearest, it paints the pixels ok, but the lines gets all fuzzy while the sprite is moving. Some lines get 2 pixels in one frame, and in other gets 1 pixel. making it "dance"..

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZf5w.jpg)
[image: Example]

So, i was wondering, is there any way to apply my shader, paint the image as i want, and only after that apply the filter? (linear would be great). That way, i whould get my pixel painted perfectly, and then the filter would make it looks good on the screen.

Or anyone have another suggestion? 
Thanks

**Edit**

As requested, here are my shaders:

Vert

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying float colora;
varying float colorb;
varying float colorc;
varying float colord;

void main() {
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
    colora = a_color.r;
    colorb = a_color.g;
    colorc = a_color.b;
    colord = a_color.a;
}
```

Frag

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

const float red0 = 0.875; // 223.125 #df0000
const float red2 = 0.625; // 159.375 #9f0000
const float red4 = 0.375; // 95.625 #5f0000
const float red6 = 0.125; // 31.875 #1f0000

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D colorTable;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying float colora;
varying float colorb;
varying float colorc;
varying float colord;

bool equalVecs(in vec4 v1, in float r) {
    return abs(v1.r - r) < 0.05 && v1.g <0.01 && v1.b < 0.01 && v1.a > 0.99;
}

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, v_texCoords);
    gl_FragColor = color;
    if (equalVecs(color, red0)) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(colorTable, vec2(0, colora));
    } else if (equalVecs(color, red2)) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(colorTable, vec2(0, colorb));
    } else if (equalVecs(color, red4)) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(colorTable, vec2(0, colorc));
    } else if (equalVecs(color, red6)) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(colorTable, vec2(0, colord));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your shader?

Comment: I updated my question with the shader

Comment: But, to clarify, my shader works perfectly in my case, but it tints only those selected colos. I need to be able to use Libgdx Image Filter "Linear", along with this shader. If i apply the filter and the shader, the shader gets all messed up, as the color isn't exactly the ones that i described anymore.

Comment: Do you also need the antialiasing from Illustrator?

Comment: No, i just need it to be antialised ( or apply filter Linear) after It has been painted by the shader. Is it possible? Or is there a shader code to make this filter myself?

Comment: Sorry, I am still unclear on what you're trying to achieve because linear filtering and antialiasing are two completely different things. If you want your curved and angled lines to look smooth, you need both. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry if im not clear,  im kind new in this. I just want to apply my shader and after that apply linear filter to my sprite. All that to achieve smooth lines after i paint my sprite.

Comment: My computer is packed up as I'm in the middle of moving so I can't test any of this. But I think what I would do is in illustrator make the black outline pure green (#00FF00) on a separate additive later and make it invisible on your base layer. Then in your shader add the green channel to your alpha and also subtract it from one and multiply that by your final RGB value from your current shader. This would keep the black from messing up your current color change logic and then you are applying after the hue is determined.